# Binding and NSPopUpButton: changing the value of the current key doesn't change the selection

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I've a really simple UI with a single `NSPopUpButton`. Its `selectedIndex` is bound to an `int` value `ViewController.self.my_selection`. As soon as I change the selection from the UI (i.e. a select the third item of the NSPopUpButton) I see that `my_selection` value changes. So far so good, what I'm trying to obtain is the opposed direction though. I want to change the `my_selection` value programmatically and see the `NSPopUpButton` selecting the item a the index that I've defined in `my_selection`. I erroneously supposed that behaviour was the default behaviour for bindings...

This is what I'm obtaining now:

```
NSPoPUpButton ---> select item at index 2 ----> my_selection becomes equal to 2
```

This is what I want to achieve (keeping also the previous behaviour)

```
my_selection ---> set value to 3----> NSPoPUpButton selected index = 3
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? In particular, how are you defining ``my_selection`` in your ``ViewController`` class?

Answer (score 2):

Without a bit more info (see my comment) it's hard to see exactly what you're doing wrong. Here's how I got it working: First, create a simple class...

```
// Create a simple class
class Beatle: NSObject {
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
    dynamic var name: String?
}
```

Then, in the `AppDelegate` I created a four-item array called `beatles`:

```
dynamic var beatles: [Beatle]?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    beatles = [Beatle(name: "John"), 
        Beatle(name: "Paul"), 
        Beatle(name: "Ringo"), 
        Beatle(name: "George")]
}
```

In Interface Builder I set things up so that this array provides the pop-up with its content:

[image]

This class also has a `selectedIndex` property that is bound to the pop-up button's `selectedIndex` binding - this property provides read-write access to the pop-up button's selection:

```
// Set the pop-up selection by changing the value of this variable.
// (Make sure you mark it as dynamic.)
dynamic var selectedIndex: Int = 0
```